# Pasar el valor de un DropDownList a una funcion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, funciones, lista

Deseo pasar el valor que se seleccionó de una lista a una función cuando ese valor cambie

Esta es la lista en cuestión:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlLista" runat="server" Width="290px" onchange="Alertando();"></asp:DropDownList>`

y debo hacer algunas cosas en esta función:

```
function Alertando(VALOR) {
if (VALOR=VALOR ESPERADO) {
alert('Se ha seleccionado VALOR como valor esperado');
}
else {
alert('Se ha seleccionado OTRO VALOR como valor no esperado');
}
}
```

qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasale un this a la función del onchange

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlLista" runat="server" Width="290px" onchange="Alertando(this);"></asp:DropDownList>
```

En tu escript ya podras obtener el valor de la siguiente forma

```
function Alertando(elemento){
    alert(elemento.value);
}
```

**Editado**

Prueba obteniendo el elemento por su id

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlLista" runat="server" Width="290px" onchange="Alertando();"></asp:DropDownList>

function Alertando(){
    var slt = document.getElementById('DdlLista');  
    var valor = slt.options[slt.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(valor);
}
```

Comment: Necesito capturar el valor del elemento... el alert me muestra un valor "undefined"...

qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Le pusiste el ***this*** al evento `onchange="Alertando(this);" `?

Comment: Sip, efectivamente se lo coloqué, pero me da el valor "undefined"

Comment: Edite el codigo basandome en lo que dice este [blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1727/get-dropdownlist-value-index-and-text-in-asp-net-using-javascript.aspx)

Comment: Excelente, así sí funcionó, muchas gracias